# Generating a CSR to a specific cipher suite

Tags: openssl, keys, csr

I am having to generate a CSR for a private RPC interface that is secured using certificates. As part of the requirements, it is specified that the only compatiable suite is:

`SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5`

My knowledge is rather limited but I have tried:

`openssl genrsa -out mykey.private -des3 512`

Then extract the public key via

`openssl rsa -in mykey.private -pubout -out mykey.public`

Then convert into a CSR via

`openssl req -new ???`

The unknown part is what parts of the cipher suites match to the parts if the CSR request, I have been told that it is a 512 bit key, however, I don't understand the relevance of the RC4 or the MD5 part!

Before people ask why I don't submit and see what happens, we get charged per CSR signing process failed or successful.

Regards,

Tom

Comment: Sounds like you need a 512-bit RSA key pair (best guess). Knowning the Cypher suite isn't nearly as helpful as knowing exactly what the application requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RC4 is a symmetric cipher which does not appear in the certificate request and in the resulting certificate itself. What can be important is the message digest algorithm; apparently your export-restricted CA requires MD5.

So first create the CSR via:

```
openssl req -new -key mykey.private -md5 -out my.csr
```

(actually `-md5` is still the default).

Then answer the prompts appropriately. After the file is generated, you can examine its contents in text form:

```
openssl req -in my.csr -text -noout
```

Make sure that the Subject, Public Key Algorithm and Signature Algorithm fields are correct before submitting the CSR; you could also see that there is no mention of RC4 or any other symmetric encryption algorighm there.

Answer (score 0):

*SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5* is cipher suite, which needs to be specified in your SSL endpoint configuration.

But just in case, make sure, that you are using -md5 when generating CSR.